# Last weekday of the month with NSDateComponents

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

`NSDateComponents` and `NSCalendar` have a feature to get the n'th weekday of the month with the `NSWeekdayOrdinalCalendarUnit` using `NSCalendarUnit`.

For example the *2nd monday of the month*.

It's awesome but, **I need to check if a certain instance of `NSDate` is the last or second last weekday of the month.** I can't think of a neat way to do this. I hope there is a simple trick that does not require you to loop through all the mondays of the whole month.

Do you guys have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add seven days (using `NSCalendar`'s `dateByAddingComponents:toDate:options:`) and check if the resulting month is the same.

Comment: So simple, love it !
Simple suggestion : the apple docs says about dateByAddingComponents:   "Note that some computations can take a relatively long time.". I guess it's for computations more complicated than adding days (for example years and months, with various lengths), but you can use too "dateWithTimeInterval:(86400*7) sinceDate:dateToTest".     
I have no idea which one is faster.

Comment: @Micazeve Just adding 7 times 24 hours might produce issues at daylight saving time changes and other subtle calendar anomalies. The reason why the proper `NSCalendar` method might take some time is because it accounts for all these anomalies.

Comment: Oh i didn't think about daylight time changes...
Thanks for your explanation !